# My program is not executing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to draw to a square on python 2.7.13 and after writing a code. I am trying to run it it always take me to shell page and displays "restart- destination of the file"?
This is my code:

```
 import turtle
 def draw_square():
    window = turtle.screen()
    screen.bgcolor("red")
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    window.exitonclick()

 draw_square()
```

This is what I am getting after execution

> ========================= RESTART: C:/Python27/a.py =========================

Comment: Hard to tell from your code snippet, but what's the indentation? To check whether it's that, remove the `def draw_square` line, the line with `draw_square()` call, then make sure all lines have no leading spaces. If that work, look at sources with info about python indentation to understand how to fix your code with the function, e.g http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

Answer (score 1):

The "screen" method is "Screen" with capital S. To draw a square:

```
import turtle
def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.left(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.left(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.left(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.left(90)
    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running it from IDLE or something similar as that gives me the "=== RESTART ===" output. Your program does not run properly for me, but this one does (capital 'S' in Screen):

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Do you get some red error messages in the shell starting like "Traceback..." perhaps?